# What difference is token in header and body?

Tags: header, token

I found a doubt when I was designing API. Some documents guide developers how to make and deal with token.

If I will access a website requiring token authentication, I should set my token in `HTTP header`, let service ascertain my validity.

Although I think designing setting up method can be flexible, for examples, setting in header or body, I don't know what difference are they?

In this token case, because token is secret info, is setting in header safer than in body? or setting in header can't make HTTP be a burden? What information does it fit with setting in header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's no special when data sets in header or body.
Except you have specail data needs to set in header, and then your web application only accepts the specify method to do. It follows you how to desgin the processing workflow.